# Is it possible to call a fragment that contains a database from firestore and make it a homefragment for navigation drawer?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I want to make a homefragment for my navigation drawer which is for my default home layout but somehow I don't get the idea what i get it wrong. The code itself doesn't error in the studio but when I opened it up, it stops working. The homefragment contains data from firestore and a recycleview.

Fragment

```java
public class Fragment_HomeSpot extends Fragment {
 private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference spotRef = db.collection("Spot");

    private SpotAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setUpRecyclerView();

    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {

        Query query = spotRef.orderBy("",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Spot> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Spot>()
                .setQuery(query, Spot.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new SpotAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_layout);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        /*
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new FragmentHome()).commit();
        }**/

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        Intent intent;

        switch (id){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new Fragment_HomeSpot()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_search:
                break;

            case R.id.nav_map:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Map.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_account:
                 break;

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```java
public class SpotAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter <Spot, SpotAdapter.SpotHolder> {


    SpotAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Spot> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpotHolder spotHolder, int i, @NonNull Spot spot) {
        spotHolder.textViewNamaSpot.setText(spot.getNama());
        spotHolder.textViewAlamatSpot.setText(spot.getAlamat());
        spotHolder.imageViewSpotIMG.setImageResource(spot.getThumbnail());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpotHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_spot_item, parent, false);
        return new SpotHolder(v);
    }

    class  SpotHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewNamaSpot;
        TextView textViewAlamatSpot;
        ImageView imageViewSpotIMG;

        SpotHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewNamaSpot= itemView.findViewById(R.id.nama_spot);
            textViewAlamatSpot = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alamat_spot);
            imageViewSpotIMG= itemView.findViewById(R.id.spot_thumbnail);

        }
    }
}
```

My Spot Class

```java
public class Spot {

    private String Nama;
    private String Alamat;
    private int Thumbnail;

    public Spot() {
        //Empty Constructor
    }

    public Spot(String nama, String alamat, int thumbnail) {
        this.Nama = nama;
        this.Alamat = alamat;
        this.Thumbnail = thumbnail;

    }


    String getNama() {
        return Nama;
    }

    String getAlamat() {
        return Alamat;
    }

    int getThumbnail() {
        return Thumbnail;
    }
}
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: can you share the logcat?

Comment: just uploaded my logcat

Comment: Update your [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) Dependencies to the latest release

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check my **[repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/main/MainActivity.java)**. I have used [Android Navigation Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) for that.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.